# drupal 7 template suggestions based on path alias

Tags: theming, path-aliases

I am using this function on a D7 site to template based on url alias and everything works except when a page has a dash in it. 
For example mysite.com/test-page doesn't work. I tried `page--test-page.tpl.php` and no luck. If I change to testpage and use `page--testpage.tpl.php` it works. 
Any ideas?

Here is the function that works:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    // Get the alias for the page being viewed
    $alias = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
    if ($alias != $_GET['q']) {
        $template_filename = 'page';

        //Break it down for each piece of the alias path
        foreach (explode('/', $alias) as $path_part) {
            $template_filename = $template_filename . '__' . $path_part;
            $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = $template_filename;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution here: 
http://cheekymonkeymedia.ca/blog/gene-bernier/how-create-page-tpl-suggestions-based-path-alias-drupal-7

Here is what I used to fix the dash in titles error. I also added no node-content-type solution:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // Get the alias for the page being viewed
  $alias = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
  if ($alias != $_GET['q']) {
    $template_filename = 'page';
    //Break it down for each piece of the alias path
    foreach (explode('/', $alias) as $path_part) {
      // Added the str_replace becayse path parts with - were not being picked up properly by the theme_hook_suggestions
      $template_filename = $template_filename . '__' . str_replace("-", "_", $path_part);
      $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = $template_filename;
    }
  }

  if (isset($variables['node'])) {
    // If the node type is "blog_madness" the template suggestion will be "page--blog-madness.tpl.php".
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'. $variables['node']->type;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hyphens in template file names are important to Drupal.  I can't think of a reason why your template doesn't work, because in my experience it probably should.

However, rather than trying to make that work,  why not eliminate the hyphens?

```
$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = str_replace(str_replace("-", "", $template_filename);
```

now you can use "page--testpage.tpl.php",  which is a file name that Drupal can make sense of.

edit: if you're worried about collisions, replace "-" with something alphanumeric.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. Strange. I am not sure why my above doesn't work?